# Typescript: Cannot read properties of null (reading "add")

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I wanted to create a role command in discord.js v13.6, but... It cannot read the line with adding a role. It gives the `Typescript: Cannot read properties of null (reading "add")` error. How do I fix it?

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const ms = require("ms");


    //!tempmute @user 1s/m/h/d

    let tomute = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!tomute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "admin");
    //start of create role
    if (!muterole) {
        try {
            muterole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                name: "admin",
                color: "#ff0000",
                permissions: []
            })
            message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (muterole, id) => {
                await muterole.overwritePermissions({
                    ADMINISTRATOR: true
                })
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.stack);
        }
    }

    await (tomute.roles.add(muterole));
    message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> стал админом`);

}
```

Comment: `tomute.roles` is `null`. `tomute.roles.add` causes this error.

Comment: What do you mean with _"how to define it"_? Where do you set it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let tomute = message.mentions.users.first();
```

This returns a user object which doesn't have role manager. You need a guild member object to be able to access the roles which can be obtained by replacing `users` with `members` in the above snippet

```
    let tomute = message.mentions.members.first();
```

read about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
let tomute = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Use

```
let tomute = message.mentions.members.first();
```

You can also use

```
let tomute = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) //to use its ID
```

Or even use it at once

```
let tomute = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

as Arnav Mentioned. Using `user` return a user object which doesn't have role manager.